# Array 3D compiles but will not run

Tags: c

When I try and make a simple 3d array `char tmp[256][256][256];` it compiles but I can't run it.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

```
int main()
{
    int tmp[256][256][256];
    getch();
}
```

That's it. It wont run.

Comment: what you need to do with this array? where is your code?

Comment: I think to be too large to be allocated on the stack. It is almost  better to ensure in such as malloc to heap, or Would you like to static.

Comment: `int main(){int tmp[256][256][256];getch();}` that's it. it wont run.

Comment: that's 64MB, that's too much for the stack.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @csaw It will compile without any issues as you said. You should post more code and provide more information on you requirement. This may be a case of stack overflow.

Comment: in your question you talk about the 3d array being of type `char`, in the code its type is `int` seems to be some confusion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey you are requesting for 256*256*256 = 16777216 byte of blocks. And this array is declare in main() method, which takes the memory on stack rather than heap. 
So try to declare this array outside the main() or use malloc() function to dynamically allocate the memory. It will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Found a nice article related to stack overflow [link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/)

Answer (score 3):

You experienced a **Stack Overflow**. How ironic!

There are **2** solutions:

**1**. **Rewrite the code** and don't request so much memory. Use **dynamic memory allocation**: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `free()` and other.

**2**. Increase the **stack memory** allocated to the program by the OS: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8cxs58a6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)